# Can't return a simple many-to-many relationship value

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, eloquent, relationship

First of all thanks for the interest in my topic. I think that this question is easy.

I have a **many-to-many relationship** created in Laravel. My **'users' table represents the users who can login in my system**. **My 'modules' table represents the modules who the user logged can access**. So, i would like to verify if the **current logged user have access to the requested module**.

For example, the user try to access the URL: laravel.com/blog/insert
But the user no have permissions for this module, so the system verify the relationships and returns if the user can continue in this page or not. I think that this validation can be done in the __construct method of the controllers.

**My tables: 'users', 'modules' and 'users_modules'**

I've tried something like this on my **'Modules' Model**, but no success. The $id represents the Module ID:

```
public static function getUser($id)
{
    $module = Modules::where('id', '=', $id)->first();

    return $module->users;
}
```

My **users** model relationship:

```
public function modules()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Modules', 'users_modules', 'user_id', 'module_id');
}
```

And my **modules** relationship:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'users_modules', 'module_id', 'user_id');
}
```

How can i do that? Thanks for everyone who helps me! :)

Comment: You don't need that static method. Anyway, it looks ok, so what's the issue? Be specific, `no success` says nothing.

Comment: Ok, when i call the static method in my index.blade.php file, the following error happens: **Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$firstname (View: /home/pedroroccon/app/views/admin/dashboard/index.blade.php)**. I call my code that way: `Modules::getUser(1)->firstname`. Firstname is a field in my 'users' table.

Comment: This is because you returned Collection of Models (since it has many related models), and you are trying to get a property of a Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem using Entrust for Laravel. Thanks all those who helped me!

**Link for Entrust:**

https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to create a custom route filter in `app/filters.php` that checks to see if the user is a member of the module in question.

Have a look at the docs [here](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters) particularly the section on specifying filter parameters, that should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: I undestand your logic, but my problem is exactly how i can verify if the user logged belongs to the current module? I'm having trouble when checking if the user belongs to the module.